# Как лучше поступить со slug?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть таблица категорий построенная по принципу `nested sets` и есть таблица записей. В записях хранится полный slug вместе с категорией, т.е. к примеру, `category/subcategory/item`. Если, к примеру, я удалю/перемещу категорию, то `slug` записи останется прежним, т.к. он генерится при создании/редактировании записи. И тут появляется вопрос, как лучше поступить - генерить нужный путь каждый раз при обращении к записи или обновлять все записи, при изменение таблицы категорий ? Т.е. к примеру мы изменили уровень вложенности категории с id = 1, значит обновляем slug для каждой записи, которая принадлежит измененной категории, т.е. в данном случае с id = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй вариант лучше будет. Поскольку операция считывания происходит гораздо чаще операции редактирования дерева категорий. Учитывая ваш подход к генерированию слагов, вам лучше менять ссылку не сразу, а с задержкой (неделя, месяц). Или хранить все старые слаги (с возможностью получения доступа по ним). Чтобы пользователи со старыми ссылками могли перейти по ссылке. Вообще стоит делать слаги такими, чтобы они не зависели от окружения.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю.

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант будет **хуже**. Он сложнее в отладке, вероятность пропуска бага выше, при этом в приложении все равно остается дефолтный дублирующий функционал, а количество энтропии и возможности выстрелить себе в ногу растет. Нет ничего плохого в оптимизированном коде, но не стоит заниматься микрооптимизациями до того момента, пока сам код не написан, да и построенные урлы лучше записывать не в базу, а в кэш, который сбрасывается консольной командой.